Is there a PLSQLDeveloper directive to always return all data?
What I am using
I'm using the latest PLSQL Developer for Oracle 12c. The IDE limits the data output of a query to how many rows fit to the screen by default. I have changed that to always the top 100, it's important for general performance that it stays like that for day to day use.
What I need
I need to send an xlsx report containing the combined data of 12 views.
Basically it's:
select * from my_view_1 where ...;

select * from my_view_2 where ...;

select * from my_view_3 where ...;

Where I need to run all queries at once, after which I copy all to xlsx.
What I do now
I need all the data, not just the top 100. That means I have to go through the tabs and click the ↓ icon manually to get everything.
It's a bit of a job, slow and easy to forget you have to do that. I would much rather just leave it running until it's done without manual intervention.
My question
I am already using a comment directive to set the title of each tab:
--TAB=My View 1 Title

Is there a directive like that to always return full data?
If not, any other methods?

I don't use PL/SQL Developer. You said "...  after which I copy all to xlsx" - how do you do that? CTRL+A selects "all" (not only the first 100 rows), doesn't it? So copy/paste copies everything. If there's something like "right-click and then select Export to xlsx", that should also affect all rows query returns. In other words: do you really have problems, you do you just think that you might have them (and try to be proactive)?

@Littlefoot right click on the result view and select Copy to Excel / Copy all as xlsx . It's a neat feature but it's loaded data only (so top 100 unless manual action).

I see ... well, I do use TOAD and its "Export to Excel" exports everything, so I hoped that PL/SQL Developer does the same.

I don't use PLSQLDeveloper but it has a feature to generate reports (see here) and you can automatically export them in XLS format so it looks like you want to generate a report rather than running the queries individually.

Looking through the User's Guide, I did a search for "directive" and that's when I saw you could do:
-- Records = All

before the query and it will override the records per page preference.

Good find! That works.

From the preferences, Sql Window you can change the record for page.
Give a chance to SQLcl could be more efficent

But then it's ALWAYS like that, which isn't what I want.

If you set ALL return all the data you want.
